# What are these files that defy file permissions to be inaccessible?

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, malware

Every once in a while in our environment the AV comes across a malicious file, usually in a users temporary internet files, that no matter what I try, I can't edit, move, copy, or in any way access the file. The really odd thing, is that if I go into the permissions and take OWNERSHIP of the file, and give myself full control, it STILL won't let me do anything with it.

Anyone have any idea what causes this, how to work around it, and if they're truly malicious? I tend to be a bit on the paranoid side and have been having the computers reimaged, just to be safe, but I'm hoping this isn't a bit of an extreme measure.

Comment: I've used [MoveOnBoot](http://www.gibinsoft.net/gipoutils/fileutil/) to handle awkward files before now - though I don't really tend to catch nasty viruses here, so idk how good it is for real sticky situations.

Answer (score 1):

If AV unable to clean the files mean, mostly it will be spyware or malware. Those can me removed by doing boot scanning. If the system was booted, it will be difficult to access those files, even if we change the permission. Hence I recommend to run boot scan to remove those spyware. There are lot of spyware cleaner are available which can do on boot scan and it will remove the spyware from your PC.